# Accessing static constant arrays from Jtwig template

Tags: java, arrays, static, classcastexception, jtwig

So, I simply cannot gather access to values in constant static arrays.

Let this be an array in my code:

```
public static int[] MY_ARRAY;
```

And this is how i trying to access that array:

```
{{ constant("com.package.configs.MainConfig.MY_ARRAY")[0] }}
```

This attempt leads to an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at org.jtwig.value.convert.collection.ArrayToCollectionConverter.convert(ArrayToCollectionConverter.java:11)
    at org.jtwig.value.convert.CompositeConverter.convert(CompositeConverter.java:15)
    at org.jtwig.render.expression.calculator.MapSelectionExpressionCalculator.calculate(MapSelectionExpressionCalculator.java:19)
    at org.jtwig.render.expression.calculator.MapSelectionExpressionCalculator.calculate(MapSelectionExpressionCalculator.java:12)
    at org.jtwig.render.expression.CalculateExpressionService.calculate(CalculateExpressionService.java:14)
...
```

I also tried to assign a constant to variable first, then accessing it, but nothing changed.

Previously, in an older versions of JTwig i was able to access any public static field of a object that i passed to the model. But now such fields are being ignored.

The version i am using is 5.86.0.
Any idea on how to beat this, or at this moment it's technically impossible?

Answer (score 0):

The exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

means the array `MY_ARRAY` is an `int`-type array, and `int` is a [primitive](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), thus it's not a sub type of [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), so **you can not cast it to an [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)-type array**.

In this case, you can change `MY_ARRAY`'s Signature to `public static Integer[] MY_ARRAY`.

[`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) wraps the `int` value in an [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

This is illustrated by the following example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];
    Integer[] arrI = new Integer[5];
    test(arr);  // error:The method test(Object[]) in the type Demo is not applicable for the arguments (int[])
    test(arrI); // ok
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the hint, this one works as intended. But what if i cannot change the code i'm trying to work with ?
Just for an instance. I can access any array (object or primitive) from Nashorn.

Comment: I don't know Nashorn, but I think it has tow or more overloading methods with different type arguments, so when you use different type arguments to call, you are actually calling different methods.